# Creating a DAX Measure to count where a subgroup is greater than 1

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset with multiple user logins and multiple districts as follows:

| User | District | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UserA | HKG | China |
| UserA | PRG | Europe |
| UserA | CKG | China |
| UserB | LHR | Europe |
| UserB | AMS | Europe |
| UserB | TYO | Japan |
| UserA | CKG | China |
| UserC | SYD | Australia |
| UserC | MEL | Australia |
| UserD | SYD | Australia |
| UserD | MEL | Australia |

I want to see the count of users that have logged into more than a single district within a region

| Region | Created Measure |
| --- | --- |
| China | 1 |
| Europe | 1 |
| Japan | 0 |
| Australia | 2 |

China has 1, because only UserA has logged into multiple China Districts
Europe has 1, because only UserB has logged into multiple Europe Districts
Japan has 0, because no user has logged into more than 1 Japan District
Australia has 2, because both User C & D have logged onto multiple Australia Districts

I have gotten close with creating a table, but I can only seem to get it to count the distinct values, not the values where the aggregate is greater than 1. This is the DAX I have so far:

```
DEFINE
TABLE UserGroup = 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        User[User],
        User[Branch],
        User[Region],
        "UserCount", COUNT('User'[User]),
        "User Distinct Count", DISTINCTCOUNT('User'[User])
        )
        
EVALUATE
    GROUPBY(
        UserGroup,
        UserGroup[Region],
        "Failing Formula", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), [User Distinct Count])
        
        )
```

Comment: Re "*where the count is greater than 1*", where the count of what is greater than 1? I think a few more examples with expected results would help clarify.

Comment: @Zabman are you sure about the desired result ?

Comment: @JosWoolley I added more examples and tried to make the problem statement a little clearer

Comment: @UmutK Yes - but I added some more examples to try to make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

```
EVALUATE


VAR allValTbl= -- DISTINCT(tbl)
        SUMMARIZE(
            tbl
            ,tbl[Region]
            ,tbl[District]
            ,tbl[User]
        )


VAR moreThenOne=
        FILTER(
            allValTbl
            ,CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(tbl))>1
        )
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        VALUES(tbl[Region])
        ,"@DCount",VAR currReg = [Region] 
                    RETURN
                    COUNTROWS(
                            FILTER(
                                moreThenOne
                                ,[Region]=currReg
                            )
                    )+0
    )
```